# Windows 10 UWP app crashes when picking contacts asychronously

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, windows-phone, windows-10-universal

While working on a Windows 10 UWP app for phone, I'm having a problem with the contact picker API object. The phone has Developer Preview 10532 installed.

I have this event handler for a button:

```
    private async void pickContactAppBar_Click (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
                ContactPicker contactPicker = new ContactPicker();
                IList<Contact> pickedContacts = await contactPicker.PickContactsAsync();
                if (pickedContacts != null)
                   int pickedContactsCount = pickedContacts.Count;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageDialog messageDialog = new MessageDialog(ex.Message);
            await messageDialog.ShowAsync();
        }
    }
```

which is supposed to give the contacts I pick with the contact picker.

The problem is, that after the contact picker window comes up, it crashes the application after a half second, right after I manage to pick a contact. It crashes even if I don't do anything after the picker is shown, but just simply wait. It seems to crash during loading of the contact list...

It happens when I deploy debug or release code, but not when I start the app from Visual Studio, by pressing F5. Also, no exception is thrown.

I'm pretty sure that I'm using async and await correctly. Since this method is an event handler it must be async void.

The method contains more code, more with await, too, but I've added MessageDialog calls to see where it ends, and it happens right after the PickContactsAsync() is called. Nothing gets executed after that. I've even commented out all other parts of its code.

Any suggestions on what could be happening? Thanks.

Comment: What's the exception?  Are you modifying the UI thread from a background thread?

Comment: @O.O, there is **no exception**. No, I'm not doing that. I'm just trying to select one or more contacts, get some of the fields from the Contact type objects returned. But the crash happens even if I have only this code in the event handler, nothing else. As soon as the picker comes up and the list of contacts starts filling up, it crashes after a half second, without any user input.

Comment: Is it good practice to have async function be called in the main page's constructor? It cannot be called with await, because the constructor cannot be made async. I have an async void Init () function which is called like that...

Comment: you shouldn't use async void for this scenario, because the construction might finish before everything has been initialized.  Also, async void is fire-and-forget, If an exception occurs during init, your program will crash, and you'll have no idea what went wrong.  Also, you'll need to put more code in your question involving the calling chain for anyone to help you more.

Comment: @O.O I changed its return value to Task, but the problem is still there. See code here: http://pastebin.com/wsxQHEur. I can reproduce it with this minimal code. there is one command button on the page, Add.

Comment: Solved: I recreated the project with the same code and it works now.

Comment: It's solved, although I couldn't figure out what the problem was...